# Django - Modify a foreign key field when updating primary field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a question. I have a relation (many-to-many) between two class and I would like when there is a relation created, update a field.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    intitule = models.TextField(verbose_name="name")
    matched = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="matched", default=True)
    asked = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="was asked", default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['intitule']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.matched) + " [" + str(self.asked) + "]" + " - " + self.intitule
```

```
class Reponse(models.Model):
    reponse = RichTextField()
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reponse
```

Here is my question: When I create an object "Response" in the admin interface and I choose a question, I would like to update the attribute "matched" in question automatically.
How can I do that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do it by writing your own view and template, otherwise you have to override your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Question, Reponse


@admin.register(Reponse)
class ResponseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user

        try:
            ques = form.cleaned_data['question'].all()
            for old_que in obj.question.all():
                if old_que not in ques:
                    old_que.matched = True
                    old_que.save()
        except:
            pass

        for que in form.cleaned_data['question'].all():
            que.matched = False
            que.save()

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.register(Question)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! And how can I do when I remove a question in Response to change the "matched" attribute to False ?

Comment: plzzz write the True and False acc to your use case. Thnx

Comment: It worked to change the value to False, thank you.
But I would like to do the opposite. I would like to change to True if the question is removed from Response but I don't how to do it.
In fact, I don't know how to get old values from the form.